# java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero in displaytag

Tags: java, displaytag

I am using display tag in portals(Struts Portal Framework) deployed in websphere portal, using external paging using value list paging (implement PaginatedList) a strong exception has shown up 
 `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero`
 
in the following lines:

```
     int pageCount = behavioursPaginatedList.getFullListSize() /  Math.max(1,behavioursPaginatedList.getObjectsPerPage());
        if ((behavioursPaginatedList.getFullListSize() % behavioursPaginatedList.getObjectsPerPage()) > 0)
    {
        pageCount++;
    }
```

FullListSize = 13
ObjectPerPage = 4

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places where divide by zero *could* occur:

```
int pageCount = behavioursPaginatedList.getFullListSize() / 
    Math.max(1,behavioursPaginatedList.getObjectsPerPage());
```

In this case, `Math.max(1, ...)` is guaranteed to deliver a value that is non-zero.  So the exception cam't be coming from here

```
if ((behavioursPaginatedList.getFullListSize() % 
        behavioursPaginatedList.getObjectsPerPage()) > 0)
```

In this case, if `behavioursPaginatedList.getObjectsPerPage()` returns zero, then you will get a division by zero error.

---

The fact that you *are* getting the exception says that division by zero *is* occurring, and that `behavioursPaginatedList.getObjectsPerPage()` *is* returning zero.  You need to find out why that is happening.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C for your reply , I do not know how getObjectsPerPage() get zero since I use debbuger to inspect its value it has  
FullListSize = 13
ObjectPerPage = 4

Comment: Add a trace print or logger call to your code immediately before the `if` statement.  Also check the line numbers in the stack trace to **make sure** you know which statement is throwing the exception.  (I suspect that either you are printing the value of `objectsPerPage` from a different object, or something is changing it *after* you print it.)

Comment: Also, beware of memory anomalies (i.e. heisenbugs) caused by incorrect synchronization in a multi-threaded application.  One characteristic of such bugs is that the symptoms tend to disappear disappear when you attempt to debug them.